# High Performance in Multitasking inside Tomcat

Tags: java, multithreading, tomcat

In my web application running tomcat 6, an object (not Servlet) is scheduled to execute for reading files from a defined folder. After reading a file, the file content is saved into a database.

In order to have higher performance, multitasking is needed. My original approach is to build a new thread once a file is read, tasks of each file run in parallel in background. For example, if three files are found, three threads are created.

However, although tomcat configuration has set maxthreads to more than 200 as well as 32GB memory has been assigned, every time only 7-8 threads are running simultaneously. What's wrong? Or multithreading is not a best practice for multitasking? Please help.

Addition (14 Mar 2014)
Thanks for your advice. So my question can be more specific:
1. Can ThreadPoolExecutor improve the performance?
2. Can NIO improve the performance?

Here is the original code:

```
String[] listFiles = folder.list();
for(int i=0; i<listFiles.length; i++) {
   synchronized(globalHashMap) {
   MyTask myTask = new MyTask(listFiles[i]);
   globalHashMap.put(listFiles[i], myTask );
   myTask.start();
   }
}

MyTask {
    String myFile;
    Thread myThread;
    public MyTask(String file) {
       myFile = file;
    }
    public void start() {
        myThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            do {
            readCnt = bufferedInputStream.read(bytesArray, 1024, 1);
            ...
            } while(not end);

            postProcessFunction();

            synchronized(globalHashMap) {
               globalHashMap.remove(myFile);
               globalHashMap.notifyAll();
            }
        }
        myThread.start();
    }
}
```

Comment: Multi threading may help you if you use it in the right way. I would recommend using `ExecutorService` instead of manually creating your threads. Also, take into account that you should not fire so many threads at all.

Comment: If your files reside in the same folder, Disk I/O is likely to be the bottleneck, i doubt that more threads hitting the same hard drive will speed things up.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. So my question can be more specific: 1. Can ThreadPoolExecutor improve the performance? 2. Can NIO improve the performance?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `maxThreads` setting in Tomcat does not mean the max. # of threads the JVM can have.  Tomcat has no control over that.  It specifies the max. # of *worker* threads Tomcat itself will create to service incoming HTTP requests.  Your Java code can still create any threads it needs.

As for why you only get 7 - 8 threads, I'd have to see the code to know for sure.  How many files are in this directory?

I am not sure what analysis you've done, but I often hear "multi-threading" as the canned solution for making something faster and that is a very dangerous way to tackle things.  Threading is meant to tackle very specific set of problems.  It should be a last resort.  Especially in a web application.  Web containers use multiple class-loaders to deploy and undeploy and redeploy applications on the fly.  Threads create a maintenance nightmare and often prevent proper class loader cleanup.

I have actually seen occasions where multi-threading masks a problem.  When I first joined my current company, an effort was underway to multi-thread the process which deploys SQL scripts against our databases to apply bug fixes.  The complaint was the process was too slow, so the solution of course was to do multiple DB's in parallel via multi-threading.  I recently discovered that the script execution process runs a SQL statement (for GRANT) at the end of every script against every database that takes 2 minutes.  This statement is rarely ever needed.  If this process was properly profiled to begin with, my recommendation would have been to remove the unneeded code, which would have dropped the process from 2-3 hours to < 10 minutes.  Now we are stuck maintaining a mess of thread management code.

So, now my question to you is, **have you profiled your code**?  As @wallenborn pointed out, disk I/O may be the bottleneck.  There could also be optimizations in your code that could be made.

Comment: There are more than 1000 files. Each file is plain text with 5000 lines, each line is less than 100 characters. After file loading, 15000 calculation is done for the file. Everytime it can process around 50 files but take very long time. In Tomcat status, only 8 threads are used. So strange.

Comment: "In Tomcat status, only 8 threads are used." - What is Tomcat status?  How are you measuring this?

Comment: 8 threads in http-8080 in tomcat server status. No web visit during the moment.

Comment: That is Tomcat's thread pool and does not include any threads you create yourself.

Comment: Yes, I know. Yet the questions are: how could I monitor my internal threads created? Why did 8 threads run if they are not my threads? How can I increase the number of simultaneous threads?

Comment: I am not sure what you are attempting to monitor so I can't answer that.  The 8 threads in question are Tomcat's HTTP executor threads.  It is normal for them to be created.  Tomcat adds and removes threads on its own based on the settings in `server.xml`.  If you are trying to create threads yourself, those settings are irrelevant.  If you are creating more yourself, then you know how many you are creating.  `ThreadPoolExecutor`'s constructors allow you to specify a min and max similar to Tomcat.

Comment: So my question can be more specific: 1. Can ThreadPoolExecutor improve the performance? 2. Can NIO improve the performance?

Comment: The only way to know is to try it.

Answer (score 1):

The MaxThreads parameter in Tomcat only controls how many threads are used for serving web requests. There is no limit (besides available memory) on how many additional threads your web application can create. There must be something wrong with the code.

Answer (score 0):

Creating new threads inside application than is run on application server is not good idea. This is bad practice. People usually say to never do this because you can run out of threads for processing http requests.

For solving your problem the best way is to utilize jms. You background task will send a message to jms broker to process each each file found on the disk. Jms broker can process messages multithreaded and very efficiently and will controll all multithreading for you.

Comment: Creating multiple threads in an application server is not a bad practice. It is not recommended unless you know what you're doing.

Comment: How about using ExecutorService and Future?